# Why is the speed of a process related to how irreversible it is?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

Almost any physics major is taught that

> By an infinitely slow process, one can change the state of a system from A to B in an irreversible manner.

Normally, the above explanation is accompanied by

> By making the process infinitely slow, you are allowing any local changes to equilibrate, so that at any given time the whole system is equilibrium.

However, I am not convinced by the idea that the slower the process, the less irreversible it gets, just because we are allowing the system to equilibrate.

As an analogy, let's say I am going from the point $A$ to the point $B$ on foot. In one case, I walk slowly and in another case, I run. From personal experience, we know that I will use & dissipate way more energy in the latter case than the former case. But nevertheless, in both cases, I go from $A$ to $B$. In other words, the fact that at any given time interval I cover less distance in the former case than the latter shouldn't matter if I am going along to the same road.

**Question:**

Why does a slow process results in a less irreversibility?

---

Note: I assume that we measure the irreversibility in terms of the entropy generated by the process(es) which start and end at fixed (but possibly different) states.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect as an answer here. The crucial part about the "slowness" of the process here in the quote you give is the assumption of equilibrium in every step and that we're talking about a *thermodynamic system*. Your example of walking has nothing to do with thermal equilibria, so it's simply irrelevant - the system 'you' walking or running is not a thermodynamic system in equilibrium.

Comment: @ACuriousMind as I've stated, it is just an analogy.